# Issues with "`GLIBC_2.32' and `GLIBC_2.34' not found" when Installing Coursier as per Scala 'getting Started' Official Instructions

Tags: scala, ubuntu, ldd, coursier

#### What I am trying to do:

I want to get started with Scala, as per https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html.

```
curl -fL https://github.com/coursier/launchers/raw/master/cs-x86_64-pc-linux.gz | gzip -d > cs && chmod +x cs && ./cs setup
```

The error I am getting:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 20.1M  100 20.1M    0     0  19.0M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 19.0M
./cs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./cs)
./cs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./cs)
```

#### OS, Java and LDD

Operating System (dual boot with Windows):
`Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`

Output of `ldd --version`:

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

JAVA (output of `java --version`)

```
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu220.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu220.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

#### Things I have tried:

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`
gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt install -y libc6 libc-bin`
gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc-bin is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.9).
libc-bin set to manually installed.
libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
```

Ultimately, I downloaded the deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/libc6/2.32-0ubuntu2. When I run `sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.32-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb` I get:

```
dpkg: regarding libc6_2.32-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 breaks locales (<< 2.32)
  locales (version 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.32-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing libc6:amd64 would break locales, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.32-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Otherwise, if I try to force it i.e.
`sudo dpkg --force-all i libc6_2.32-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`, I get:

```
dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
```

Comment: It's already an issue on their [Github](https://github.com/coursier/coursier/issues/2624), which was closed 19 hours ago and will be fixed in the next release

Answer (score 2):

You may try the static compiled version of the cs:

https://github.com/coursier/launchers/raw/master/cs-x86_64-pc-linux-static.gz

At least in my setup this worked.